# Java EE 6 and CDI

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, cdi, java-ee-6

I'm just starting learning CDI and Java EE 6 but I found this piece of code that I want to fully understand.

```
@Stateful
@Model
public class MemberRegistration {
   @Inject
   private EntityManager em;

   @Inject
   private Event<Member> memberEventSrc;

   private Member newMember;

   @Produces
   @Named
   public Member getNewMember() {
      return newMember;
   }
}
```

Then... I saw that a jsf page referenced this `newMember` object like this:

```xhml
<h:inputText value=#{newMember.name}/>
```

So my question is : It doesn't matter if I put an `@Named` annotation inside an variable of any object, it will be accessible anyway from JSF code?
Also, what's the usage of `@Produces` in this case, and finally is `@Stateful` preferred over `@Stateless` in Java EE 6? If that's the case why?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Despite its simplicity this bean sure does a lot of things ;)

Either the `@Named` (CDI) or `@ManagedBean` (JSF-native) annotation is required to make a bean known to JSF. However, Java EE has the concept of `stereotypes`, which are a kind of composite annotations that combine a number of other ones.

In this case [@Model](http://seamframework.org/Documentation/WhatIsThePurposeOfTheModelAnnotation) is such a stereotype, it combines `@Named` and `@RequestScoped`.

`@Produces` annotates a factory method; a method that knows where to get an instance of some type from. It can be combined with a so-called qualifier annotation, e.g. `@Foo`, after which you can use that annotation to inject something in some bean. In this case however it's combined with `@Named`, which makes `newMember` available to JSF. Instead of creating the bean as would happen when e.g. an `@RequestScoped` bean is encountered first, under the covers the `getNewMember()` method will be called when JSF wants an instance. See [Dependency Injection in Java EE 6](http://www.theserverside.com/feature/Dependency-Injection-in-Java-EE-6-Part-5) for more info.

`@Stateful` is normally not preferred over `@Stateless` when used standalone. `@Stateless` beans are pooled and execute one method for a client (typically in a transactional context). Their stateful counterpart is not pooled and without CDI, the caller has to keep track of its life-cycle (by eventually calling an `@Remove` annotated method). Here, the bean is also assigned a scope (request, via `@Model`), so the container will take care of that.

The likely reason for using this annotation here is probably to make the bean's methods transactional. Although the fragment as given doesn't show its usage I guess there's a version of this class with more methods that make use of the `EntityManager`. Transactions will come into play there.

*(Note, combining annotations this way gives the Java EE developer lots of power, but it does put several concerns in one bean which is contrary to the mantra that a bean should do one thing and do that well. An alternative is an `@Model` annotated bean focussing on view concerns only, that's injected with `@Stateless` beans that encapsulate the business logic instead of an `EntityManager`.)*